# Modem toggle in PAP2 in dial plan?

Tags: voip, modem, fax

I use a Linksys PAP2 for my fax line and I can toggle modem mode by dialing *99 before the number, however I do not want to have to dial it every time to send a fax. Is there any way to incorporate the modem toggle into the dial plan ? I have googled and haven't found anything, I'm afraid the answer may be no, but I wanted to give this a try.
I know faxing over IP is not reliable, yet, I would still like to entertain it. Are there are other analog adapters that are more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

suppose its the same number you want to use for sending the fax, lets assume its "16131234567" just add the following rule in your dial plan. (|<16131234567:*9916131234567>|)
when you will dial the fax number ATA will automatically add *99 before it.

Answer (score 0):

My pap has the *99 modem code too.  I researched this some time ago.  *99 does the following: Force dtmf inband, echo cancel off, echo supress off, silence supress off, force g.711/ulaw, and call waiting off.   In respect to modems and fax, due to the half duplex nature of fax, there may be a benefit of using echo cancellation.  Most any normal dial up is where it's best disable of the echo canceller, not fax.  However, some may be using "echo suppress", and/or silence suppression, both of which hurt fax greatly.

In terms of making fax reliable over Voip, the number one best thing you can do is complain, complain, and complain to your ISP and get them to reduce the packet jitter on your line!  There is T.38 to experiment with which was designed to work with jittery lines, but not all ata's and providers support it.  However, there is no real "better" ata then another ata for fax and modems.  Voip uses primarily g.711/ulaw codec, which is what the PSTN uses.  It's mainly the high packet jitter on many residential lines that make fax not work.  The local nodes can be oversold, but they generally want to deliver high speed (quantity), not low jitter (quality).

Oh! the one biggest myth going around is to disable ECM mode. DON'T!  Ecm mode was invented just for improving success rates over noisy and unreliable phone lines.  In fact, ECM helps greatly with Voip.  Turning off ECM is "I don't care if my faxes are unreadable" mode, going back to the early 80's with fax machines were thermal roll.  Turning off ECM will increase the apparent "success" to you because there will be fewer errors given to you by your machine in front of you.  However, pages may be missing or cut in the middle, unreadable, etc. but your machine will indicate a "success".  I’ve heard from too many people that leaned the hard way when it occurred to them because people were telling them that pages were missing, etc.

One last thing I want to touch on is baud rate, generally many machines have two modes: no ecm 9600, and ECM 14400, and if you have it, super g3 33600.  Of course, SG3 is going to give the most problems.  Generally reducing the baud rate below 14400 isn’t necessary, since it's not a big jump, and 14400 is more tolerant to noise anyhow.  Don’t switch to 9600 if it means disabling ECM mode.